# How to skip an iteration in a for-loop in Scala?

Tags: scala, loops, iteration

For example in C you would be able to write

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
  if (i == 2) i += 1
  // do stuff
}
```

Since Scala uses ranges, how would we modify the iterator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a guard:

```scala
for (i <- 0 to 10; if i != 2) println(i)
```

This would print the numbers from 0 to 10, excluding 2.

You can see this code in action an play around with it [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/eWheJKNYRsmWep1UCHSCcA/1) on Scastie.

Answer (score 3):

You would have multiple solutions, but basically using a .filter() like clause somewhere should do it.

Like `(0 to 10).filterNot(_ == 3).foreach(doStuff())` for example

Comment: Great :-) don't hesitate to flag one of the answers you found relevant has accepted :-) (if both were, you can pick at random it's all fine :-) )

Comment: Thanks :) I'll also come back when I am able to vote, to upvote both answers